# How to get scroll height at element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

i want to get all scroll -y height of elemetns with style overflow-y:scroll
I've the next code:

```
    <div class="team_comments">
<div class="col span_9">
<div id="timelineBoxContainer">
<ul id="timeline" class="clearfix">
<li>
<li>
<li style="display:none;">
<li style="display:none;">
<li style="display:none;">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    .team_comments {
    height: 310px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

    #timeline:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8E9399;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 99999px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 2px;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
#timeline {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

how i can get the height of scrollbar at .team_comments ? (not current position!!!)? I think that scrollbar geight must be equal position of scroll top when it the end.
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure its possible to get the height of the scrollbar as such. The scroll position and scrollable distance (which is called scrollHeight) are gettable though.

Comment: What about http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: i don't need current scroll position, i try to understand that scroll is at the end. Like at infinite scroll

Comment: This is my solution!
jQuery('.team_comments').scroll(function(){
if(this.scrollTop==this.scrollHeight-this.clientHeight)
{
    alert('end');
}
});

thanks